# Multiple isset queries in one if loop

Tags: php, post, boolean-logic, isset

I'm trying to get the following query:
**If exists value of A and value of B OR if there is a value of A OR if there is a value of B ----> DO SOMETHING**

```
if((isset($_POST['A'], $_POST['B'])) OR !empty($_POST['B']) OR !empty($_POST['A']))
    {
        echo "there is something:" . $_POST['B'] . ", " . $_POST['A'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "its empty<br />";
    }
```

When in one of the fields is a value works correctly, but when we have empty both fields is still apparent that something exists.

Is wine may lie with autocomplete?

```
$checkVIN1 = mysql_query("SELECT vhl_vin FROM vhldescription");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkVIN1);
$i = 0;
echo "<script>$(function() {var availableTags = [";
while($checkVIN2 = mysql_fetch_array($checkVIN1, MYSQL_ASSOC))  {   $i++;   echo "\"" . <br />$checkVIN2['vhl_vin'] . "\",";
    if ($i == ($num_rows))  {   echo "\"" . $checkVIN2['vhl_vin'] . "\"";   }   }
echo "];$( \"#tags\" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});});</script>";
<input id="tags" name="A" class="le-input">
```

Comment: [`mysql_` functions are deprecated.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)

Comment: put an elseif condition to tighten your check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
$a;
$b;


if((isset($a) or isset($b)) and !(empty($a) or empty($b))){
    echo "do something";    
}else{
    echo "do nothing";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to this:

```
$postVars = array('A', 'B');
$things = array();
foreach($postVars as $postVar) {
    if( isset($_POST[$postVar]) && !empty($_POST[$postVar]) )
    {
        $things []= $_POST[$postVar];
    }
}

if( empty($things) ) {
    echo "it's empty<br />";
} else {
    echo "there is something: "
         . join(', ', array_map(function($str) {
                                    return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');        
                                },
                                $things)) . '.';
}
```